# How to locate a value from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I made a list with two values in each cell.

```
list={{{494.5, 399.5}, {565.5, 470.5}, {580.5, 535.5}, {794.5, 
   749.5}, {830.5, 840.5}, {1280.5, 1290.5}}, {{518.5, 399.5}, {589.5,
    470.5}, {604.5, 535.5}, {718.5, 728.5}, {854.5, 864.5}, {1304.5, 
   1314.5}}};
```

For example I want to find out if the number 430 falls between the two values, I can see with eye that it falls between {494.5, 399.5} but how do I write the code in such a way that it tells me if  430 falls between {494.5, 399.5} ?

and if 430 falls between {494.5, 399.5}, I want to find out the location of {494.5, 399.5} in the list too.

Thank you for your help. I have been trying to solve this problem for a while but with no luck

Comment: ``Select[Catenate@list, Between[430, Reverse@#] &]``, and then something like ``Position[Catenate@list, #] & /@ %`` to get positions.

Comment: indexes = Flatten@Position[list, {x_, y_} /; Between[430, {{x, y}, {y, x}}] == True] then list the items via: foundList = list[[indexes]]

Comment: Notice that the documentation for `Between` says that the interval is assumed to be sorted, but in reality, doesn't need to be. When did this behaviour change?

Comment: @rhemans, interesting. There actually seems to be a bug in the documentation, saying that ``Between[3, {5, 2}]`` is ``False`` when in fact it returns ``True`` in 12.3.

Comment: @Domen, Just dropped a line to wolfram support reporting this problem with the documentation. 
Honestly, I like this behaviour better than requiring the interval to be sorted.

Answer (score 6):

I would take advantage of [`IntervalMemberQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMemberQ.html)

We can define a function

```
whereinrange[lst_, val_]:=Position[lst,_?(IntervalMemberQ[Interval[#]][val]&),{-2}]
```

then use like this

```
whereinrange[list,430]
(* {{1,1},{2,1}}  *)
```

This works also if the list has a different structure

```
whereinrange[Flatten[list, 1],430]
```

As pointed out by @Domen, [`Between`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Between.html) seems to be an even better option. Notice that you don't need to sort the values of the interval.

```
whereinrange2[lst_, val_]:=Position[lst,_?(Between[#][val]&),{-2}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{{494.5, 399.5}, {565.5, 470.5}, {580.5, 535.5}, {794.5, 
     749.5}, {830.5, 840.5}, {1280.5, 1290.5}}, {{518.5, 399.5}, {589.5, 
     470.5}, {604.5, 535.5}, {718.5, 728.5}, {854.5, 864.5}, {1304.5, 
     1314.5}}};
```

The positions are given by

```
pos = Position[list, _List?(#[[1]] > 430 > #[[2]] &)]

(* {{1, 1}, {2, 1}} *)
```

The corresponding elements are

```
list[[##]] & @@@ pos

(* {{494.5, 399.5}, {518.5, 399.5}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

based on the comment of @Domen

```
 data = Flatten[list, 1]; cells =Select[data, Between[430, #] &]

 {{494.5, 399.5}, {518.5, 399.5}}
```

and then location

```
loc= Position[data, #] & /@ cells

{{{1}}, {{7}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list =
  {{{494.5, 399.5}, {565.5, 470.5}, {580.5, 535.5}, {794.5, 749.5}, {830.5, 840.5}, {1280.5, 1290.5}}, 
   {{518.5, 399.5}, {589.5, 470.5}, {604.5, 535.5}, {718.5, 728.5}, {854.5, 864.5}, {1304.5, 1314.5}}};
```

Using `Position` and `Extract`

```
p = Position[list, x_ /; Between[430, x], {2}]
```

{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}

```
Extract[p] @ list
```

{{494.5, 399.5}, {518.5, 399.5}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{{494.5, 399.5}, {565.5, 470.5}, {580.5, 535.5}, {794.5, 749.5}, {830.5, 840.5}, 
       {1280.5, 1290.5}}, {{518.5, 399.5}, {589.5, 470.5}, {604.5, 535.5}, {718.5, 728.5},
       {854.5, 864.5}, {1304.5, 1314.5}}};
```

---

Using `Cases` at level `2`:

```
Cases[list, x_ /; Between[430, x], {2}]

(*{{494.5, 399.5}, {518.5, 399.5}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {{{494.5, 399.5}, {565.5, 470.5}, {580.5, 535.5}, {794.5, 
     749.5}, {830.5, 840.5}, {1280.5, 1290.5}}, {{518.5, 
     399.5}, {589.5, 470.5}, {604.5, 535.5}, {718.5, 728.5}, {854.5, 
     864.5}, {1304.5, 1314.5}}};

(pos = list /. v_?VectorQ :> IntervalMemberQ[Interval[v], 430]) // 
 Position[True]
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}

```
Pick[list, pos]
```

{{{494.5, 399.5}}, {{518.5, 399.5}}}